# How to perform transformations using ProjNet?

Tags: .net, coordinate-system, proj, sharpmap

While writing some unit tests I thought it would be convenient/possible to use ProjNet to convert from EPSG:4326 into several other coordinate systems (3875,3395).  I figured it would be as easy as grabbing the WKT values from spatialreference.org:

- http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/ogcwkt/
- http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3395/ogcwkt/
- http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/ogcwkt/

Add a reference to ProjNet and running the following code:

```
var cf = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.CoordinateSystemFactory ( );
var f = new ProjNet.CoordinateSystems.Transformations.CoordinateTransformationFactory ( );
var sys4326 = cf.CreateFromWkt ( wkt4326 );
var sys3857 = cf.CreateFromWkt ( wkt3857 );
var sys3395 = cf.CreateFromWkt ( wkt3395 );
var transformTo3875 = f.CreateFromCoordinateSystems ( sys4326, sys3857 );
var transformTo3395 = f.CreateFromCoordinateSystems ( sys4326, sys3395 );
```

But 3857 and 3395 could not be parsed.  I googled around and found a workable 3857 though I haven't confirmed it produces a correct result.  I continue to get an error parsing 3395 (*Expecting ('PROJECTION') but got a 'UNIT' at line 1 column 296.*).

Perhaps the "OGC WKT" can be modified in a predicable way to work with ProjNet?  Or perhaps ProjNet is not the best .NET solution for re-projecting coordinates?

```
const string wkt4326 = "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]";
const string wkt3857 = "PROJCS[\"Popular Visualisation CRS / Mercator\", GEOGCS[\"Popular Visualisation CRS\", DATUM[\"Popular Visualisation Datum\", SPHEROID[\"Popular Visualisation Sphere\", 6378137, 0, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7059\"]], TOWGS84[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6055\"] ], PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\", 0, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\", \"8901\"]], UNIT[\"degree\", 0.0174532925199433, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\", \"9102\"]], AXIS[\"E\", EAST], AXIS[\"N\", NORTH], AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4055\"] ], PROJECTION[\"Mercator\"], PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\", 0], PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\", 0], PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\", 0], PARAMETER[\"Latitude_of_origin\", 0], UNIT[\"metre\", 1, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\", \"9001\"]], AXIS[\"East\", EAST], AXIS[\"North\", NORTH], AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"3785\"]]";
const string wkt3395 = "PROJCS[\"WGS 84 / World Mercator\",GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],PROJECTION[\"Mercator_1SP\"],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",0],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",1],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"3395\"],AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH]]";
```

Comment: http://projnet.codeplex.com/discussions/268940 discusses 3857 issue.

Comment: Moving the AUTHORITY to be final element in the WKT resolves this issue.  Make sure the WKT follows the syntax diagram shown [here](http://projnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Well-Known%20Text&referringTitle=Home)

<coordinate system> = <projected cs> | <geographic cs> | <geocentric cs>
<projected cs> = PROJCS["<name>", <geographic cs>, <projection>, {<parameter>,}* <linear unit>]
<projection> = PROJECTION["<name>"]
<parameter> = PARAMETER["<name>", <value>]
<value> = <number>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error (with a different SRID). Solution was to use the/an **[Esri WKT on spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4283/esriwkt/)**, which does not cause an issue with the ProjNet CoordinateSystemWktReader

Comment: Very good info and should probably be the answer!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I found that manually conforming my WKT to the BNF described [here](http://projnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Well-Known%20Text&referringTitle=Home) eliminates the errors.  Content repeated below:

```
<coordinate system> = <projected cs> | <geographic cs> | <geocentric cs>
<projected cs> = PROJCS["<name>", <geographic cs>, <projection>, {<parameter>,}* <linear unit>]
<projection> = PROJECTION["<name>"]
<parameter> = PARAMETER["<name>", <value>]
<value> = <number>

<geographic cs> = GEOGCS["<name>", <datum>, <prime meridian>, <angular unit>]
<datum> = DATUM["<name>", <spheroid>]
<spheroid> = SPHEROID["<name>", <semi-major axis>, <inverse flattening>]
<semi-major axis> = <number> NOTE: semi-major axis is measured in meters and must be > 0.
<inverse flattening> = <number>
<prime meridian> = PRIMEM["<name>", <longitude>]
<longitude> = <number>

<angular unit> = <unit>
<linear unit> = <unit>
<unit> = UNIT["<name>", <conversion factor>]
<conversion factor> = <number>

<geocentric cs> = GEOCCS["<name>", <datum>, <prime meridian>, <linear unit>]
```

So for my specific problem (EPSG:3395) the resulting WKT would be:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / World Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0], // required, missing from spatialreference.org
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3395"]]
```