# How to transform Lambert coordinates in C#?

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, coordinates, lambert-conformal-conic

I want to transform Lambert (EPSG:3035) coordinates to EPSG:4326 in C#.

I have tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23425/how-to-perform-transformations-using-projnet):

```
var lambert = cf.CreateFromWkt("PROJCS[\"ETRS89 / ETRS-LAEA\",GEOGCS[\"ETRS89
\",DATUM[\"European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989\",SPHEROID[\"GRS 
1980\",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7019\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6258
\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree
\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4258
\"]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_center
\",52],PARAMETER[\"longitude_of_center\",10],PARAMETER[\"false_easting
\",4321000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",3210000],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG
\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"X\",EAST],AXIS[\"Y\",NORTH],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"3035\"]]");
```

Error: Projection Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area is not supported.

As far as I understand, ProjNet should support Lambert. Can someone help me? Or show me another way how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dotspatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/) to make your transformation. The two projections is created by:

```
//EPSG 3035
ProjectionInfo fromProjection = KnownCoordinateSystems.Projected.Europe.ETRS1989LAEA;
//EPSG 4326
ProjectionInfo toProjection = KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984;
```

And you make the transformation with

```
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(fromPoint, toPoint, fromProjection, toProjection, 0, 1);
```

Comment: A bit late, but I will accept this answer. I am not working with C# anymore, but I will accept it anyway for the following reasons: 

(1) dotspatial is still actively maintained & provides the mentioned classes: https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial
(2) the example code is quite straight forward and obvious. If the class name or method names changes a bit in the future, it should be easy to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me but this code is not right

```
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(fromPoint, toPoint, fromProjection, toProjection, 0, 1);
```

ReprojectPoints should be called like this:

```
Reproject.ReprojectPoints(fromXY, fromZ, fromProjection, toProjection, 0, 1);
```

fromXY is an array with 2 doubles (X and Y) and fromZ is an array with 1 double (Z).

The function returns the result in the fromXY variable.

But for me it does not work for ETRS89LAEA anyway. just get NaN in the result...

If anyone got conversion to ETRS89LAEA to work with dotspatial, please show me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code (`CreateFromWkt`) and the exact error message you are getting, I suspect you are using [ProjNet4GeoAPI from NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI)

I had the exact same error, when trying to convert coordinates based on the [EPSG:3035](https://epsg.io/3035) system to WGS84 using the [1.4.1 version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ProjNet4GeoAPI) of this library.

For me, the solution was to use the newer [2.0 version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ProjNet) of this project (called ProjNET), which supports the Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area projection.

**Note 1**: this new version has breaking changes regarding the previous (1.4.1) version. But most of these changes are small.

Ex. `ICoordinateSystem` (interface) => `CoordinateSystem` (class)
And some dependencies (like Geo.Api…) are removed.

**Note 2**: at the moment the project isn’t actively maintained, so when you’re looking for something new, you might want to look for another library (like suggested at the ProjNET GitHub page).
But when you are using the older version, you can upgrade to the newer version with more projections quiet easely.